# firebase updates while app runs in the background

Tags: cordova, firebase, angularfire

How to set up firebase to continue issuing updates/sync even while the app is running in the background? Or the app has been "idle"/not actively opened for days/weeks like social apps (Facebook) but can still get updates?  I am developing a hybrid mobile app and using AngularFire.

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for push notifications. Send a push notification to the app.

Comment: Thanks @Kato for the response. How does this affect concurrency (if I'm using the right term) or the persistent connectivity with firebase? Does my app need to be constantly connected to the firebase URL? Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert in mobile, so take all of this for what it's worth. As I understand, the OS controls backgrounding of apps. This is beyond the app's control. There are some exceptions--such as voip apps--but for the most part the OS decides when sockets are closed and when the app can send out for updates. A push notification is a way of "waking up" an app to tell it to go get updates.